# Removing Image Metadata in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I'm currently developing a React Native app where I need to remove metadata from images. The app involves users uploading images, and for privacy reasons, I would like to strip all EXIF metadata from these images before they are processed.

Is there a good way to remove image metadata in a React Native app? Are there any libraries compatible with React Native that can handle this, or any native modules that I could use for this purpose?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Image metadata including EXIF  not standardized across all platforms and OEM device manufacturers. There's no simple universal solution to split them in each image.

In case you preview user-uploaded or camera-taken images before the user uploads them.

It will help if you use https://github.com/gre/react-native-view-shot to take the same image shot and upload that image.

This new image data will not contain any private user information.